# DB2 SQL How to split a column into potentially many rows?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I've got a table with 2 fields (ID & Profile).

Table has lots of records, but is unique by ID.
Profile is 1000 characters long, and each 10 characters is a basically a Profile code.
Some ID's may have just 1 code, whilst others have many.

I don't know why the table was designed like this.

So a record might look something like:

```
ID              PROFILE
BOB             BM        BS        DM        FM        IC        IC6       IL        IM        JN101     MM        XC        XM        XR
BILL            ZZ        XY
```

Is there a way to split the Profile field, making new rows

So it would look like:

```
ID              PROFILE
BOB             BM
BOB             BS
BOB             DM
...
BILL            ZZ
BILL            XY
```

I'd really like to be able to create a View somehow.

Comment: Platform and version of Db2 are important to note.  With Db2 for IBM i v7.3 and higher, IBM has included a `SPLIT()` [function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajq/rzajqudfsplit.htm) for you...

Comment: We're using Db2 for IBM i v7.3 - I'll look into SPLIT(). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

## DB2 for LUW

```
/*
WITH TAB (ID, PROFILE) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('BOB',  'BM        BS        DM        FM        IC        IC6       IL        IM        JN101     MM        XC        XM        XR')
, ('BILL', 'ZZ        XY')
)
*/
SELECT T.ID, V.TOK
FROM TAB T
, xmltable
(
'for $id in tokenize($s, " +") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
passing T.PROFILE as "s" 
columns 
  tok varchar(10) path '.'
) V;
```

[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d2f26b1ba62affd66db3dc0e4f2db7ec).

## DB2 for LUW & IBM i

IBM i doesn't support (at least up to 7.4) FLWOR XQuery expressions, so you need to construct an XML document.

```
SELECT T.ID, V.TOK
FROM 
  TAB T
, XMLTABLE 
(
'$doc/d/i'
PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<d><i>' || regexp_replace(trim(T.PROFILE), '  +', '</i><i>') || '</i></d>') as "doc"
COLUMNS 
  TOK VARCHAR(10) PATH '.'
) V;
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that but got an error.
"An XPath expression has an unexpected token string($id) following {."
I wouldn't know how to fix this.

Comment: What’s your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: Db2 for IBM i v7.3

Comment: @Anson You should tag your question properly. I've added the `db2-400` tag to your question and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. That works great. I didn't know about all the available tags so thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

Tried using split(). It seems very slow. Below takes 14.817 sec.

```
WITH TAB (ID, PROFILE) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('BOB',  cast('BM        BS        DM        FM        IC        IC6       IL        IM        JN101     MM        XC        XM        XR' as char(1000))), 
  ('BILL', cast('ZZ        XY' as char(1000)))
)
SELECT a.id, b.element as profile
from  tab a, 
      TABLE (systools.split(a.profile , ' ')) b
where b.element <> '';
```

Compared with Joachim's answer taking only 134 ms!

```
WITH TAB (ID, PROFILE) AS 
(
VALUES 
  ('BOB',  cast('BM        BS        DM        FM        IC        IC6       IL        IM        JN101     MM        XC        XM        XR' as char(1000))), 
  ('BILL', cast('ZZ        XY' as char(1000)))
)
SELECT a.id, b.item as PROFILE
  from tab a
      ,XMLTABLE('$doc/items/item'
          PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT CAST(   '<items><item>'
                                         || replace(a.profile , ' ' , '</item><item>')
                                         || '</item></items>' as CLOB
                                        )
                           ) as "doc"
          COLUMNS
          ITEM VARCHAR(255) PATH '.'
      ) b 
WHERE b.item <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the SYSTOOLS.SPLIT function but she's behaving very strangely... I don't know what's going on...
Very slow and buggy with long string as parameter !?!

```
CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSTOOLS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
[2020-10-22 17:04:59] 0 rows retrieved in 86 ms (execution: 51 ms, fetching: 35 ms)
[2020-10-22 17:04:59] [0F001][-423] [SQL0423] Pointeur SQLP_L2.VWORK incorrect.
[2020-10-22 17:04:59] [0F001][-423] [SQL0423] Pointeur SQLP_L2.VWORK incorrect.
[2020-10-22 17:30:29] 5 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 255 ms (execution: 41 ms, fetching: 214 ms)
CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSTOOLS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
[2020-10-22 17:30:29] 5 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 251 ms (execution: 39 ms, fetching: 212 ms)
CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSTOOLS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
[2020-10-22 17:30:30] 5 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 253 ms (execution: 39 ms, fetching: 214 ms)
CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSTOOLS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
```

## DB2 for IBM i

Here is my custom SPLIT function from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189396/6632535/)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UTILS.Split (String VARCHAR(32000), SEP VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS TABLE (ID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(256))
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DISALLOW PARALLEL
  DETERMINISTIC
  NOT FENCED
  RETURN

  WITH CTE (ID,StartString,StopString) AS
  (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS StartString, LOCATE(SEP, String) AS StopString
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    WHERE LENGTH(SEP) > 0 AND LENGTH(String) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 1, StopString + LENGTH(SEP), LOCATE(SEP, String, StopString + LENGTH(SEP))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE StopString > 0
  )
  SELECT
    ID,
    SUBSTRING(String,StartString,
      CASE WHEN StopString = 0
      THEN LENGTH(String)
      ELSE StopString-StartString END
    )
  FROM CTE;

CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (UTILS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
[2020-10-22 17:30:32] 5 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 50 ms (execution: 36 ms, fetching: 14 ms)
CHECK> SELECT * FROM TABLE (UTILS.SPLIT('4182511-S_4182701-X_4182702-X_4182703-X_4182796-S' , '_'))
[2020-10-22 17:30:33] 5 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 63 ms (execution: 38 ms, fetching: 25 ms)
```